# "ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO" when trying to add NFC reader RC522

Tags: nfc

I am trying to add a NFC tag reader to my model4B pi. I have been using the guide on [this page](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/02/rc522-rfid-tag-read-raspberry-pi/?moderation-__hash_=%20815149cb41468fa513818524f42803d3)

I have added the reader to my pi, using female to female jumper cables, using the diagram provided.

I have managed to install the libraries but on that particular guide when I get to the stage where I can start using their test scripts, I get the following error:

```
pi@USR:~/MFRC522-python $ python Read.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Read.py", line 24, in <module>
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
ImportError: No module named RPi.GPIO
```

I have googled and tried various things, but I'm at a loss as to what direction to go from here.

Comment: Try running with Python3: 'python3 Read.py'

Comment: What OS? What Pi? Why are you trying an ancient tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial I linked to was a vey old tutorial, and I found one that was more recent and led to a successful conclusion: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/

I also soldered my board properly and it's all working now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).